# Google function for uploading files has error Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large)

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, file-upload, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

How to resolve the problem with google storage and google function and uploading files. When I want to upload file 40MB I have an error:

> Error 413 (Request Entity Too Large).

I should use a google function or maybe app engine. Small files I can upload without any problems but for larger than 32MB function doesn't work.